# Where is bashrc profile for root?

Tags: bash, root, bashrc

I believe the question says it all.

Also if it doesn't exist where do I create it.

Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You will find it in the home folder of root:

```
/root/.bashrc
```